# How to convert a random number to another base format?

Tags: python, math

I want to pick a random number and express that number in the format of a lottery system. For example, a lottery system has 7 groups of 2-digit numbers from 01 to 40 with the total possible combinations of 163,840,000,000 (40 to the 7th power). If I pick a random base-10 number, say 453,867,221, How can I express that in 7 groups of 2-digit numbers from 01-40?

My programming language of choice is Python, although any language/pseudo language will help.

Comment: A real lottery doesn't allow repeats. You'll need to code for that too.

Comment: Remember that log2(40^7) is about 37.3, so you need 38 bits to represent the maximum value as an integer.  You'll have to be sure to use a long for the binary representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have 40-base numbers with 7 40-base "digits". Converting them to an integer is relatively simple (I'm using explicit loops to make things clearer):

```
digits = [12, 5, 39, 1, 40, 8, 17]
total = 0
for digit in digits:
    total = total * 40 + (digit-1)
```

Converting back is just the reverse:

```
total = ...
digits = []
while total > 0:
    digits = [(total % 40 + 1)] + digits
    total = total / 40
```

Comment: You want to subtract 1 from each digit converting to integer, and add 1 when converting from integer.  Base 40 has 'digits' 0-39.

Comment: Why not use digits.append() ?

Comment: Or rather digits.insert(0, total % 40 + 1). Or append() and then reverse in the end. Neither is a big deal though.

Answer (score 7):

The standard library's `random.sample` chooses n values from a population without replacement:

```
>>> import random
>>> ' '.join('{:02d}'.format(n) for n in random.sample(xrange(1,41),7))
'25 19 15 09 01 26 06'
```

But here's exactly what you asked for, including the possibility of repeated numbers:

```
import random

def display(n):
    for _ in range(7):
        d,n = n % 40 + 1, n // 40
        print '{:02d}'.format(d),
    print

display(0)       # test lower limit
display(40**7-1) # test upper limit
display(random.randint(0,40**7-1))
```

Result:

```
01 01 01 01 01 01 01
40 40 40 40 40 40 40
18 23 27 14 23 31 38
```

Comment: +1 for elegance and non-wheel-reinvention. (also for the use of `_` as a don't-care, which I forgot you could do.)